# Select Customers who purchased one specific Product

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two tables:

1. Customers:

[image]

2. Products:

[image]

The goal is to select [Id] and [CustomerName] of Customers who purchased Milk **AND** did not purchase Bread. In the case the correct query should return a customer with Id 2 (Ann).

The query which I thought of (and which is obviously incorrect) is:

```
select CustomerName from dbo.Customers
where Id in 
(
  select CustomerId from dbo.Products
  where ProductName = 'Milk' and ProductName != 'Bread'
)
```

It returns two customers: 1 (John) and 2 (Ann).
How to rewrite the query so it would return only customer with Id 2?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? And are the products only milk and bread?

Comment: Something messed up about your database design.  Why would there be a column `CustomerId` in table `Products`?  Why would you have duplicated `ProductName` in your `Products` table?  Probably learning database design should be the first thing you should do.

Comment: @scsimon Microsoft SQL Server. The products are only milk and bread.

Comment: @Eric I understand it makes little sense, but normalization is not the case here.

Comment: To piggy-back on @Eric: It seems that this table really represents __purchases__, not __products__. Presumably (hopefully), the `ProductName` attribute is a foreign key to a table that actually stores product information (e.g. product price). Normalization is always a priority and should be taken into consideration with (relational) database development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the query below

```
SELECT CustomerName 
FROM dbo.Customers c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Products
    WHERE CustomerId = c.Id
        AND ProductName = 'Milk'
) AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Products
    WHERE CustomerId = c.Id
        AND ProductName = 'Bread'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use two `exists`, just use `where` clause with `not exists` :

```
select c.*
from customer c
where ProductName = 'Milk' and
      not exists (select 1 from Products p where p.CustomerId = c.id and p.ProductName = 'Bread');
```

Comment: `Customer`table doesn't have column `ProductName`.

Answer (score 1):

I am inclined to use aggregation for this.  Here is one method:

```
select c.customerId
from dbo.Products p
where p.productName in ('Milk', 'Bread')
group by c.customerId
having sum(case when p.productName = 'Milk' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when p.productName = 'Bread' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

You can add the `join` in to get the customer name, if you really need that.

Basically, this counts the number of rows for each customer that have `'Milk'`.  The `> 0` says there is at least one.  It then counts the number of rows that have `'Bread'`.  The `= 0` says that there are none.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Id ,C.Customers 
FROM Customers AS C , Product AS P
WHERE (C.Id = P.CustomerId)
AND (P.ProductName = 'Milk') 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Products
    WHERE CustomerId = C.Id
        AND ProductName = 'Bread'
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

If normalization is not the case, efficiency isn't either. Here you go:

```
select CustomerName from dbo.Customers
where
   Id in (select CustomerId from dbo.Products where ProductName = 'Milk')
   and Id not in (select CustomerId from dbo.Products where ProductName = 'Bread')
```

Ah. Just saw it could be considered a duplicate of Eric's answer. Using exists may be a little faster indeed.